# Error al actualizar Genexus 17u8 a Genexus 18u2 iOS, cocoapods Xcode 14.2

Tags: ios, genexus, cocoapods

Migrando una App desde Gx17u8 a 18u2.
Tengo las cocoapods actualizadas, y seguimos los pasos que se indican en el SAC #42942.
[image: cocoapod instaladas en la MAC]

Nosotros usamos proxy y es por eso que en el archivo MacTransfer.exe.config, hasta el momento le seteamos lo siguiente:

< add key="CocoaPodsCommandLinePath" value="export https_proxy=http://proxy:puerto;/usr/local/bin/pod"/>"

Cuando mando a compilar con esta key, da el siguiente error(van dos imágenes):
[image: Error al compilar con Key del proxy img_1]
[image: Error al compilar con Key del proxy img_2]

Cuando lo hago sin esa Key en el archivo:
[image: Error al compilar sin Key del proxy]

Answer (score 0):

Por si alguno se pasa por este Post... quizás le pueda servir lo siguiente:
Si elimino el proxy de la ecuación(ni la Mac con salida por proxy, ni la pc con Gx y sin la key en el archivo MacTransfer.exe.config) funciona todo perfecto, por lo que me inclino a pensar que se introdujo algún Bug en Gx para cuando es necesario agregar el proxy al archivo MacTransfer.exe.config.
Pero bueno, en la realidad de nuestra organización no es posible trabajar sin proxy(fue solo una excepción para eliminar variables).